# How to pass the FormCollection object for testmethod during Unit Testing 

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are Facing an issue of passing the FormCollection while unit testing. Is there a way to simulate these FormCollection directly without having to set individual parameters. It becomes very tedious process of initializing each and every object value for huge forms. I suppose there can be a direct way of doing it. Does anyone have idea about it ?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than rewrite the code to fill the FormCollection for every unit test, create a method in your test class that generates a valid FormCollection that you can use for each test.  You can add/remove/modify parameters from this "base" FormCollection to suit the needs of each unit test.  This way you only have to write most of the code once for filling the FormCollection.